# Embed multiple iframe srouces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to dynamically play one iframe src after the other. These are videos but do not have an extension of .mp4 or any video formats. For example I am using YouTube embeds below.

Thank you for your help.

```
<iframe id="example_frame_1" width="100%" height="100%" src= "https://www.youtube.com/embed/EcJwUCJvU7I?autoplay=1" onended="run()"/>

<script>
    iframe = document.getElementById("example_frame_1");

    function run(){

        var nextFrame = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/EcJwUCJvU7I?autoplay=1";
        iframe.src = nextFrame;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: What is not working as you expect?  Provide your expected output and any error messages you receive

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073494/can-javascript-detect-when-an-embedded-youtube-video-has-ended

Comment: @EatPeanutButter:I have two videos embed in iframe source. Both should play one after the other. Currently only first video is playing and the second video is not working.