# Does YouTube API support for parameter to close browser after particular time?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Does YouTube API support for the parameter close the browser after particular time?

this need to achieve for promoting the promo video using links to share on a different location. and as soon as the video is ended. close the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Youtube API to monitor is the video is finished then use javascript codes to close the browser.

```
// when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {            
            alert('done');
          //do something here

        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Gznb/

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11726088/5995040
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27073513/5995040

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Mr.Rebot, this is helpful but i am not looking for the script. I want to use only URL like https://www.youtube.com/embed/hhtUg3v-KyE?autoplay=1 so here autoplay=1 will play video automatically so i am looking for such parameter to close the browser as soon as video is finished playing